# How do I name a Python dictionary after a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm attempting to create dicts of currency information from the coinmarketcap API and name each dict after the currency symbol. End goal:

```
# see coinmarketcap data entered into the dict
print(BTC['price']  + "\t$" + BTC['marketCap'])

# add arbitrary data to the BTC dict that other dicts might not have
BTC['founder'] = "Satoshi Nakamoto"

# see data from multiple sources in any given dict
print(BTC['symbol']  + " was founded by " + BTC['founder'])
print(LTC['symbol']  + " " + LTC['isMineable']  + " mineable")

BTC was founded by Satoshi Nakamoto
LTC is mineable
```

However, when I get coinMarketCapTicker['symbol'], and it's a string "BTC", I'm having a hard time creating a dict called BTC from that value.

```
import requests
import json

tickerURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=100"
request = requests.get(tickerURL)
coinMarketCapTicker = request.json()

while True:
    for x in coinMarketCapTicker

        tickerSymbol = x['symbol']

        # load current symbol's dict with the rest of the data from the API
        tickerSymbol = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}

    break
```

This makes a dict called 'tickerSymbol' that gets overwritten for every symbol, instead of dicts named BTC, ETH, LTC, etc

I've tried this instead, but they don't work:

```
x['symbol'] = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}
```

and

```
str(x['symbol']) = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}
```

I'm a little stuck, any ideas?

Comment: You could make a dict of dicts.

Comment: That would be great - except the bottom dict needs to be called something, then I'm having the same issue.

I can't do 'if symbol = BTC then create BTC{}' for every symbol I get on the API without making an if statement for each symbol that *might* come in

So I'm trying to do it programmatically

Comment: Why the same issue?  Call the outside dict `dict_of_symbols` or some such...

Comment: dict_of_symbols(BTC, LTC, ETH) is the idea.

Totally great - just trying to figure out how to name the BTC dict 'BTC' when 'BTC' is the string for 'symbol' currently in the API-processing loop

Comment: `dict_of_symbols = {}` then `dict_of_symbols['ETH'] = {...}`.  That is a dict of dicts.

Comment: Yep, exactly - but the string 'ETH' is coming in from the api as the variable: x['symbol'].

and I can't figure out how to use that string to make a dict called ETH

Comment: `dict_of_symbols[x['symbol']] = {...}`

Comment: OK, testing this: **dict_of_symbols[x['symbol']] = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}** So then to get BTC price, I'd do this, then? **print(dict_of_symbols.BTC['price'])**

Comment: It is a dict, use `['BTC']` not `.BTC`

Comment: *forehead* yep. That works, thank you very much. I named the dict-of-dicts 'ticker', so this: **ticker[x['symbol']] = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}** is in the loop, and just before the break, a **print(ticker['LTC']["price"])** outputs '148.227'. which is the current USD price of Litecoin.

Comment: Note, it is possible to dynamically create a variable based on a string, however, it is almost assuredly the case that you really just want a dict. Indeed, in Python, the global namespace is really just a dict, accessable through `globals()`. Once you understand how to use a `dict` you will know exactly how to create gloval variables dynamically. But then, you should stop and think, why pollute the global namespace? Why not keep your program organized and use a dedicated `dict`? Note: local variables are a little more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, one way to solve this is by having one dictionary for every symbol with all of the details inside, and one dictionary a level up with every symbol dictionary within it.

I named the dict-of-dicts 'ticker', so this creates a dict named with 'symbol'...inside a master directory dict called 'ticker'. Entire symbol dicts are used as ticker[''], and individual elements as ticker[''][""]

In practice with the code I posted:

```
ticker[x['symbol']] = {"symbol" : x['symbol'], "price" : x['price_usd'], "marketCap" : x['market_cap_usd']}
```

is in the loop, populating ticker with symbol dicts **and** filling in the symbol dicts at the same time. Just before the break, a:

```
print(ticker['LTC']["price"])
```

outputs '148.227' (the current USD price of Litecoin), which shows data from a random symbol extracted from the API feed is correctly stored and available.